# JS get and insert into <script>

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing this code **for an extension** but It returns:

**`Origin chrome-extension://gjganecebobheilkbpmhmocibjckgidc is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`**

```
var randomstring = '';var jsid = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<20; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz".length);
        randomstring += "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz".substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
function addS(file){
        var xmlHttp = null;
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", file, false );
        xmlHttp.send( null );    
        jsid  = jsid + 1;
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        // s.src = file;
        s.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        s.async = "true";
        s.id = randomstring+"_unique"+jsid;
        s.className = randomstring;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
    }
```

addS('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js');
   addS('http://domain.com/functions.js'');

I would use jQuery but I can't **because it breaks the source code of the page**, what I want is to do the same as this, but in javascript and skipping that error

```
function addS(file){
    jsid  = jsid + 1;
    $.get(file, function(data) {
    var string = '<script type="text/javascript" async="true" id="'+randomstring+"_unique"+jsid+'" class="'+randomstring+'">'+data+'</script>';
        $('head').append(string);
});
```

**Additional Info**
I'm gonna insert `jquery.js` and `functions.js` with an ID like this tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" async="true" id="AWhAXksocT6o6OrBxT28_unique1" class="AWhAXksocT6o6OrBxT28"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/functions.js" async="true" id="AWhAXksocT6o6OrBxT28_unique2" class="AWhAXksocT6o6OrBxT28"></script>
```

with this code:

```
function addS(file){
        jsid  = jsid + 1;
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = file;
        s.async = true;
        s.id = randomstring+"_unique"+jsid;
        s.className = randomstring;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
}
```

I need this ID (via var randomstring) to keep alive, that's the main problem because I will need to delete both after function ends but it returns 
`functions.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: randomstring is not defined` using this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Functions loaded");
    //Do some functions....
    $("."+randomstring).delete();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious as to what's preventing you from using jQuery.

Comment: @mblase75 it's an extension and jQuery prevents original code from working. Let's say, it's like Facebook.

Comment: Well, your error sounds like you're trying to access an external file using AJAX in violation of the security rules. If that's the case, you're out of luck.

Comment: @mblase75 im not exactly violating that rules, I updated the question so you can understand the working...

Comment: innerHTML may not work for script elements. Better set its [text property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-81598695).

Comment: So what should I do, updated question

Comment: Wrt to your last edit: You are aware, that removing the script element does _not_ delete any objects/functions/whatever created by the script inside that element? To remove everything you have to resort to namespacing and remove the contents of a namespace inside of the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't perform a cross-domain ajax request unless the domain you are requesting from implements CORS.

What you are doing currently IS a cross-domain ajax request. If you instead do as Sirko suggested and request it by making the src of the script element you are appending the url to the ajax request, it will properly make the request.

```
function addS(file){
    //var xmlHttp = null;
    //xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //xmlHttp.open( "GET", file, false );
    //xmlHttp.send( null );    
    //jsid  = jsid + 1;
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = file;
    //s.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    s.async = "true";
    s.id = randomstring+"_unique"+jsid;
    s.className = randomstring;
    document.head.appendChild(s);
}
```

What is the purpose of this function? In what context is it used? What does it accomplish?

Comment: @Luis - I don't see where you are defining `randomstring`

Comment: So, your delete code isn't working, right? Can you post that too?

Comment: Where is that snippet of code located? For it to work, it would have to be in the same file as the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you're just pasting the content of a file into the `script` tag.
So why not pass the file url directly to the `src` parameter of the `script` tag instead?

```
function addS( file ) {
  var scriptEl = document.createElement( 'script' );
  scriptEl.setAttribute( 'src', file ) ;

  document.head.appenChild( scriptEl );
}
```

Comment: @Luis you could append all additional information to the respective `script` tag using `data-*` attributes. I think, I'm still missing your problem here.

Comment: So what should I do? I need to use jQuery but I can't because it breaks the page code.

Comment: @Luis Two appraoches: For the first take a look at the [jQuery docu](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries). The other one depends on how much you are bound to jQuery or if you can extract some of its functions and move them to a different namespace to prevent collusions (Assuming that this is, what "break your page code").